# Bash command `Ctrl+u` truncate current input line instead clearing it

Tags: linux, bash

These days I've encountered an weird Bash issue.In terminal, when I press command `ctrl+u` and want to clear current input line, instead of clearing it, sometimes it will truncate current input line by leaving certain letters starts from the beginning.

For example, in below example, I first press 4 times `ctrl+p` to find the recently typed commands. Then when I stop at the `ls /Users/Heros/dev/gitinspector/gitinspector-0.3.2` command. And now I press `ctrl+u`. The current input line not completed cleared as shown from the picture. It leave `ls /Users` there.

I have been googling this issue for days but with no luck. Does anybody encounter this similar issue before? Any clue provided will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

BTW, i am using Bash and the terminal I am using is iTerms2. I tried the standard Terminal app and the issue still there.

[image]

To help the investigation, I pasted the `~/.bash_profile` I am using, in case it will helps.

```js
# Add Homebrew `/usr/local/bin` and User `~/bin` to the `$PATH`
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

GRADLE_HOME='~/dev/gradle-2.4'
export GRADLE_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
export PATH

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
      [ -r "$file" ] && source "$file"
  done
  unset file

alias gitinspector='~/dev/gitinspector/gitinspector-0.3.2/gitinspector/gitinspector.py'

#export java env
export JAVA_6_HOME='/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home'
export JAVA_7_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home'
export JAVA_8_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home'

#add JAVA_OPTS
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m"
export JAVA_OPTS

#switch  among jdk6/7/8
alias jdk6='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_6_HOME'
alias jdk7='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_7_HOME'
alias jdk8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME

alias jshint='~/.npm/jslint/0.9.0/package/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint' #add jshint env
alias chrome='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"'   # open an url or html from command
alias xee='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Xee.app"'
alias thunder='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Thunder.app"'
alias macdown='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/MacDown.app"'
alias notes='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Notes.app"'
alias pdf='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Preview.app"'
alias gif='/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/LICEcap.app"'

#add maven env
MAVEN_HOME=$HOME/dev/apache-maven-3.3.3
M2_HOME=$HOME/dev/apache-maven-3.3.3
PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
export MAVEN_HOME
export M2_HOME
export PATH

alias fq="~/dev/code_sh/auto_gfw.sh"
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias listen="lsof -P -i -n"   
mcd() { mkdir -p "$1";cd "$1";}  #enter into dir once a dir created
cls() { cd "$1"; ls; }   #list after enter into a dir

extract() {
    if [ -f $1 ]; then
        case $1 in
            *.tar.bz2) tar xjf $1 ;;
            *.tar.gz) tar xzf $1 ;;
            *.bz2) bunzip2 $1 ;;
            *.rar) unrar e $1 ;;
            *.gz) gunzip $1 ;;
            *.tar) tar xf $1 ;;
            *.tbz2) tar xjf $1 ;;
            *tgz) tar xzf $1 ;;
            *.zip) unzip $1 ;;
            *.Z) uncompress $1 ;;
            *.7z) 7z x $1 ;;
            *) echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()";;
        esac
    else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
    fi
}

#add path for mysql
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#rvm
export PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

#set bash to use vi mode as default rather than emacs
#set -o vi
function rvm_version {
  local gemset=$(echo $GEM_HOME | awk -F'@' '{print $2}')
  [ "$gemset" != "" ] && gemset="@$gemset"
  local version=$(echo $MY_RUBY_HOME | awk -F'-' '{print $2}')
  [ "$version" != "" ] && version="$version"
  local full="ruby$version$gemset"
  [ "$full" != "" ] && echo "$full "
}

#function parse_ruby_version {
  #ruby -v | cut -d" " -f2
#}

function color_my_prompt {
    #local __user_and_host="\e[m"Shibin"@\h $ "
    local __user_and_host="\e[\033[36m\]"Shibin"@\h $ "
    local __cur_location="\[\033[01;34m\]\w"
    local __git_branch_color="\[\033[31m\]"
    #local __git_branch="\`ruby -e \"print (%x{git branch 2> /dev/null}.grep(/^\*/).first || '').gsub(/^\* (.+)$/, '(\1) ')\"\`"
    local __git_branch='`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`'
    local __prompt_tail="\[\033[35m\]$"
    local __last_color="\[\033[00m\]"
   # local __rvm_color="\[\033[01m\]"
    #export PS1="$__user_and_host $__cur_location $__rvm_color$(\rvm_version) $__git_branch_color$__git_branch$__prompt_tail$__last_color "
    export PS1="$__user_and_host $__cur_location $__git_branch_color$__git_branch$__prompt_tail$__last_color "
}
color_my_prompt
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR GVM TO WORK!!!
[[ -s "/Users/Heros/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/Heros/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
```

Comment: What happens if you use a different terminal, for example the standard Terminal app? That would at least tell you where the problem might lie.

Comment: Good catch, I just tried the standard Terminal app, same issue there. To help investigate, I also edited my original post by adding my `~/.bash_profile` configuration file. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get a workaround, by just disabling the `color_my_prompt` function, issue gone. I copied this function from online before, current I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Anyone who find the root cause, I will accept your answer, thanks.